# Select random row for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, group-by, window-functions

I have a table like this

```
ID    ATTRIBUTE
 1    A
 1    A
 1    B
 1    C
 2    B
 2    C
 2    C
 3    A
 3    B
 3    C
```

I'd like to select *just one* random attribute for each ID. The result therefore could look like this (although this is just one of many options

```
ATTRIBUTE
B
C
C
```

This is my attempt on this problem

```
SELECT
  "ATTRIBUTE"
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    "ID",
    "ATTRIBUTE",
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "ID" ORDER BY random()) rownum
  FROM
    table
  ) shuffled
WHERE
  rownum = 1
```

however, I don't know if this is a good solution, as I need to introduce row numbers, which is a bit cumbersome.

Do you have a better one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select distinct on (id) id, attribute
from like_this
order by id, random()
```

If you only need the attribute column:

```
select distinct on (id) attribute
from like_this
order by id, random()
```

Notice that you still need to order by `id` first as it is a column of the `distinct on`.

If you only want the distinct attributes:

```
select distinct attribute
from (
    select distinct on (id) attribute
    from like_this
    order by id, random()
) s
```

Comment: but this would return EVERY attribute in a random order, not just one per ID, or do I misunderstand your code?

Comment: @speendo The `distinct on (id)` makes it return one only row per id

Comment: laughed like this :D

Comment: No syntax like this in mysql is there? :)

Answer (score -1):

Put a big random number in front of each record (id) and choose within each group the record with the lowest random number.

```
$ cat test.txt
\N  1   a
\N  2   b
\N  2   c
\N  2   d
\N  3   e
\N  4   f


$ mysql

USE test;
DROP TABLE test;
CREATE TABLE test (id0 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id VARCHAR(1),  attribute VARCHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY (id0));
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/mysql/test.txt' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';

DROP TABLE rtest;
CREATE TABLE rtest (random INT(8), id0 VARCHAR(1), id VARCHAR(1),  attribute VARCHAR(1),  PRIMARY KEY (id, random));

INSERT INTO rtest
SELECT CAST(1000000. * rand() AS INT) AS random, test.* FROM test;

SELECT rtest.* FROM rtest,
(SELECT id, min(random) AS random FROM rtest GROUP BY id) AS sample WHERE rtest.random=sample.random AND rtest.id=sample.id;
```

Comment: wouldn't the result always have the same order, even though its random the first time.