# Select a random distinct row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql called **drugs** with 3 columns (id,illness,drug).
An *illness* may occur several times in the column but with different *drug*.

I need a code to select a distinct ilness but it should use a random criteria so that it can display different *drug*.

Example in mydb...

```
id | illness | drug
------------------------------
1  |malaria  |panadol    
2  |malaria  |hedex  
3  |malaria  |tripple action    
4  |fever    |panadol
```

i tried this but it wasn't random in picking the rows for drug. selected only a single drug for malaria all the time.

```
$quotes="SELECT drug,remedy FROM drugs group by drug";
```

### i need this outputs

```
 1   | malaria   | panadol or hedex or tripple action **//any but random**  
 2   | fever     | panadol **//random drug if i add other rows of fever**
```

Comment: `drug` criteria is random...do u have to catch random `illness` too?? or are u giving an `illness` in `where` clause?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044828/select-random-row-for-each-group your question is answered for postgre, Try so that may be useful in mysql too

Comment: show what you need as output

Comment: check my question, i have made some edits to show the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$quotes="SELECT drug,remedy FROM drugs WHERE id = (1+ RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM drugs)) group by drug";
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). yet i have the various rows in my database.

Comment: Put your ans here after running it 3-4 times.                          SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM drugs))

Comment: `SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM drugs));`   gives the output 0,3,4,2,7,3,1

Comment: what max id you have in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Or in mysql

`$select = 'select * from drugs order by rand() limit 1';`

That will get the rows at random, and then limit answer just for one of it.
You can add `where` clause to the query as well.